# What is meant by filesize and datasize in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am started using MongoDB few days ago, and i have problem in understanding some database architecture. If i execute the query db.stats(); i had got filesize ,datasize,storagesize & indexsize. While i am surfing i found that the following:

Storagesize = datasize + free space allocated for collection

datasize = database size utilised by MongoDB

Here, I could not understand  the representaion of filesize & datasize reprsentation. For datasize --> indexsize is also included?. Please provide a precise solution for the specified attributes and please do correct me if i mentioned anythng wrong.

Advance Thanks,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- dataSize : Sum of all actual data (BSON objects) used by the database, in bytes
- indexSize : Sum of all indexes used by the database, in bytes
- storageSize : dataSize plus all preallocated collection space, in bytes
- fileSize : Sum of the sizes of all files allocated for this database (e.g. test.0 + test.1 etc.), in bytes
- nsSizeMB : Size of namespace file for this database, in megabytes.
- avgObjSize : Average size of document objects in database. This value includes padding and may therefore not change when you reduce the size of documents.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [this post](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-mongodb-performance-metrics-mmap/) about the different MongoDB performance metrics you should monitor (with MMAPv1), here are all the storage size metrics returned by dbStats that you should track:

- `dataSize` measures the space taken by all the documents and padding in the database. Because of padding, `dataSize` decreases if documents are deleted but not when they shrink or get bigger following an update—those operations just add to or borrow from the document’s padding.
- `indexSize` returns the size of all indexes created on the database.
- `storageSize` measures the size of all the data extents in the database. **With MMAPv1**, it’s always greater than or equal to `dataSize` because extents contain free space not yet used or freed by deleted and moved documents. `storageSize` is not affected when documents shrink or are moved.
- `fileSize` corresponds to the size of your data files. It’s obviously always larger than `storageSize` and can be seen as the storage footprint of you database on disk. It decreases only if you delete a database and is not affected when collections, documents, or indexes are removed.

Here is a diagram with the different important storage metrics returned by dbStats: 
[image: dbStats storage metrics for MongoDB]
NOTE: With the MMAPv1 storage engine, MongoDB pre-allocates extra space on the disk to documents so efficient in-place updates are possible since documents have room to grow without having to be relocated. This extra space is called *padding*.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an older question, but I figured I'd link to the official docs for `db.stats()` for anyone else looking for similar info (as I was).

[Database Statistics Reference :: Fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-statistics/#fields)