# Why dis-similarities in MongoDB Database Used Space Architecture?

Tags: mongodb

We have started using MongoDB few days ago but We couldn't understand why there is so Dis-Similarities with Total Disk Space Used by MongoDB and Data-base size Used by MongoDB. My Concern is as follows:

When we execute the query db.stats(); we saw the details as follows:

- DataSize : 232.68MB
- storageSize : 292.58MB
- Indexsize : 204.51MB
- avgObjSize : 171MB

If we check in the database location, total file size (test.0+test.1+test.2..etc) is "2.8GB". 
In the event of adding the [datasize+storagesize+indexsize+avgobjsize = 900.77MB] why it's not equal to the physical space used by the Disk "2.8GB". Apart from datasize, storagesize, indexsize, avgobjsize what else space is allocated for MongoDB. Can u please provide us your precise suggestion.

Advanced Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Data Size is the amount of space the actual document uses.

Storage size is the amount of space allocated internally for the documents.  MongoDB automatically adds padding to the actual document size to make updates not require a move on disk.  Therefore storage size is typically larger than data size.  Think of this as a virtual filesystem on top of the actual file system.

FileSize is the amount of space allocated on disk in the host OS's filesystem.  This is done in 2GB increments and typically is larger than the storage size.

Running compact or repair on a collection can shrink the storage size by removing the padding.  This is most often useful in the case where a document grew on disk & then some data was removed.  It still takes up the maximum size in storage size, so if you have a lot of churn on growing & then shrinking, this can help recoup space.

FileSize never will shrink unless you move it to another system, since the space has been allocated on disk for use by MongoDB.  However, shrinking storage size can reduce the need for another FileSize alloc, thus effectively re-using space previously allocated.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB allocates some space for future use. At any given moment there should be no more than 4 GB of this extra space.

Comment: Hi @Sergei Tulentsev, Thanks for your kind information. One of our techie said that the storage-size is the one which is represented by data-size plus free-space allocated for collection. According to his explanation the free space is allocated is included in storage-size then why we have more size in database storage location. I meant the size of test.o,test.1...etc. Please provide remedy to this case. Once again Thanks.

Comment: Is this little extra space a problem? Because you can't really fix it.

Comment: As far as I know, storage space includes things actually stored (data and indexes). Extra space is not accounted in this value.

Comment: Hi @Sergei Tulentsev, Thanks for your information. Could you explain about fileSize and difference between fileSize and StorageSize..

Comment: fileSize should be equal to combined size of all your `test.x` files (excluding `test.ns`). It includes free space (obviously).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446651/what-is-meant-by-filesize-and-datasize-in-mongodb