# Can I compute fileSize for a MongoDB database without using dbstats?

Tags: mongodb, size, filesize

There is [a dbstats call in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-statistics/) that gives you the true size of your database on disk as fileSize. However, dbstats is not suitable for use in production, because [it blocks the database server while it runs, and it can run for a long time](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Monitoring+and+Diagnostics#MonitoringandDiagnostics-mongoShellDiagnosticCommands). There is [a collstats call](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/collection-statistics/) that is purportedly safe (per a colleague), but its return value doesn't have a fileSize member, only a storageSize member. Here's [an explanation of dbstats().dataSize, fileSize, and storageSize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9025881/253309), claiming that storageSize and fileSize are different. The [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-statistics/) is ambiguous, but I have confirmed the difference empirically:

```
> MB = Math.pow(2, 20)
> db.stats(MB)
{
    "db" : "somedb",
    "collections" : 11,
    "objects" : 68200,
    "avgObjSize" : 1153.922991202346,
    "dataSize" : 75,
    "storageSize" : 117,
    "numExtents" : 34,
    "indexes" : 17,
    "indexSize" : 8,
    "fileSize" : 448,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "ok" : 1
}
>
```

Is there a way to compute the true size of a MongoDB database on disk using server APIs without blocking the server for 15 minutes?

**Update:** I'm specifically looking for a server API. My use case is adding disk usage statistics to [Mongs](http://www.whit537.org/mongs/), a db browser, which can't assume direct filesystem access.

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongostat does not help you?

Comment: I'm not seeing that mongostat shows me size on disk. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.

Storage size is the amount of space allocated internally for the documents. MongoDB automatically adds padding to the actual document size to make updates not require a move on disk.

FileSize is the amount of space allocated on disk in the host OS's filesystem (including preallocated space). The data files are allocated on a per DB basis and start at 64 MB and double in size until they reach 2 GB (after which each subsequent data file is of 2 GB size). The naming of data files are in the format dbname.0, dbname.1 ...

To find the file size you could use simply use linux commands (ls -l, du -h etc.) on all the data files and sum up the values or you could use du -ch *regex* to find the combined value for all of them.

Comment: Thanks for responding here and on mongodb-user. However, I'm specifically interested in "using server APIs."